# Forking a Javascript function with JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to make a login page, but the users to login may have different roles, and need to go different places. The trouble is I don't quite understand how to retrieve this data. The data is collected in an HTML form and the Javascript code is like this.

```
let form = document.getElementById("login").addEventListener('submit', login);

async function login(e){
let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
let password = document.getElementById("password").value;

let user = {
    username,
    password
}
try{
    let req = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    });
    let res = await req.json();
```

The data then gets directed to a fuction to check validity, and returns 200 or 403. The object retrieved by the validity function gets written to the session object if it is valid.

From here, I can easily redirect the user to a new page with `location.href =`, but how do I handle if I want to redirect the user based on criteria that can be found in the object returned by validity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the returned object with if/else, for example:

```
const res = await req.json();
// lets say the data object looks like this:
// { username: string, role: "default" | "premium" | "admin" }
const data = res.data;
if (res.role == "default") location.href = "https://www.test.com/default";
else if (res.role == "premium") location.href = "https://www.test.com/premium";
else if (res.role == "admin") location.href = "https://www.test.com/amdin";
```

Keep in mind that this is a very simplified example and you wouldn't solve that problem like this. Normally you handle the redirect on the backend and in case you are developing a SPA and you use React/Vue/whatever you would normally just render the information on the screen and working with the history API rather than just redirecting a User on the Frontend with JS. Depending on whether you actually check if the person who opens the admin link is in admin, the security level on handling redirection on the Frontend is rather low. If there is no reason for you to handle this on the frontend, I personally would recommend you to do this kind of things on the backend.

Comment: Handing on the back end is simple enough, but how to let the frontend know where to go?

Comment: Ok, took me a bit, but found the right reference